# Launching Outlook from Powershell, a way to bypass the warning popups?

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to launch outlook from PS, but I get 3 areas of code that ask for me to Allow or Deny to proceed.   Is there a way to bypass these warnings?  My group's status on the domain is a slightly stripped down version of a Domain Admin.

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)  
$Mail.Recipients.Add("me@me.com")
$Mail.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail" 
$Mail.Body = " PS Test "
$Mail.Attachments.Add("C:\scripts\test.txt")
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: What version of Outlook? Maybe you can look at this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/59d2aadc-f5a5-4e1d-b787-f1f20eb7e70b/powershell-how-to-disable-outlook-popup-a-program-is-trying-to-access-email-addresses?forum=ITCG) for reg key edits to disable those?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, Outlook is 2010.  Unsure what the exchange is.  Think the admins recently upped to 2010 as well.  Ill check out that link and give it a shot tomorrow morn at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to make sure an up-to-date anvirus product is installed (if you can control the client environment) or use Redemption or Clickyes to work around the security prompts. See  http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for more details.